# add alt attribute to image with php

Tags: php

I've got this code

```
<img id="aw_popup_close_btn" onclick="Popup.hideWindow();return false;" 
         src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/close_label.gif');?>" alt="close" >
```

However, when I inspect the code it doesn't show the alt attribute. Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**Update** adding a semi colon to the alt attribute fixed it so `alt="close;"`

Comment: instead of inspect, check the view source and put the rendered tag here

Comment: alt is what it uses if it can't load the picture. If you want mouseover text, it's the title attribute.

Comment: Sorry that's what I meant, when I check the page source it's not there so it must not add it

Comment: Please put your rendered code

Comment: <img id="aw_popup_close_btn" onclick="Popup.hideWindow();return false;"
             src="..../images/close_label.gif">

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you get a PHP error in the `getSkinUrl` function which is not displayed.
Turn on display_errors in .htaccess to see if you have any errors:

```
php_flag display_errors on
```

Answer (score -1):

Try anyone from below, it might help you.

```
<img id="aw_popup_close_btn" alt="close" onclick="Popup.hideWindow();return false;" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('popup/images/close_label.gif'); ?>" >

<img id="aw_popup_close_btn" onclick="Popup.hideWindow();" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('popup/images/close_label.gif'); ?>" alt="close" >
```

Comment: Why might it help?

Comment: Sometimes if you complete your php ending tag just after end of line it causes a problem. As he did it above 'close_label.gif');?>"'. Do you think that could be the reason?

Comment: I don't believe that is a problem. But I'm happy to be proven otherwise :)

Comment: I would also like to see the other way if this is not correct. ;)

Comment: Thanks, but no that wasn't the issue